# What is an equivalent jQuery implementation of this Prototype JS ajax form post?

Tags: javascript, jquery, prototypejs

How do you convert this Prototype Ajax call to a jQuery implementation that functions the same way?

JS:

```
<script style="text/javascript">
    function checkit() {
        var request = new Ajax.Request('/checkit', 
        {
            asynchronous:true, 
            evalScripts:true, 
            parameters: $('checkit_form').serialize(true)
        });
    }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<form id="checkit_form">
 <input type="hidden" id="hashedEnumerable" name="hashedEnumerable" value="X101933488ccf103hghs029sskxiiefdhsYs"> 
</form>
```

Comment: what causes the function checkit() to run?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
function checkit() {
    var request = $.ajax({
        url: '/checkit',
        data: $('#checkit_form').serialize()
    });

    return request;
}
```

The `return` statement isn't needed, but it allows you to say:

```
var x = checkit();
x.success(function() { /* DO STUFF */ });
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not particularly familiar with Prototype, but I think the code will look something like this:

```
$.ajax('/checkit', 
    {
        data: $('#checkit_form').serialize()
    }
);
```

jQuery's default settings are for scripts to be evaluated and for AJAX to be asynchronous.  IIRC, this is true for Prototype as well, so those lines were unnecessary in your prototype example.

You could also do this with the [`$.get`](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.get) helper:

```
$.get('/checkit', $('#checkit_form').serialize());
```

This is a shorthand for the above code.